# Issue with a function

Tags: python, recursion

The user enters the KGs (e.g. 1800), which should be converted to cubic meters, and the function should return the result.

Here's my code:

```
def volume_per_container(kg_cargo_per_cubic_metre):
    """Given the kg of cargo per cubic metre, calculate how many cubic metres
    of cargo can be stored in a single container."""
    max_volume_cubic_metres = 65.7
    max_net_load = 26199

    cubic_metre = kg_cargo_per_cubic_metre / max_net_load
    if cubic_metre >= 65.7:
        return volume_per_container (kg_cargo_per_cubic_metre) == max_volume_cubic_metres
    else:
        return volume_per_container (kg_cargo_per_cubic_metre) == cubic_metre
```

I get this error:

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You call the function in itself which in turn calls it in itself and so on.

Comment: Your algorithm is wrong. You are always calling the function at the end of it, again, and again, and when you call it more times than Python allows by default (you can change this value by `sys.setrecursionlimit(...)`, though it doesn't cause your particular problem), you get the RecursionError.

Comment: Would you mind changing the title of your question to something more informative?  "Issue with a function" is very vague.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do like this:

```
def volume_per_container(kg_cargo_per_cubic_metre):
    """Given the kg of cargo per cubic metre, calculate how many cubic metres
    of cargo can be stored in a single container."""
    max_volume_cubic_metres = 65.7
    max_net_load = 26199

    cubic_metre = kg_cargo_per_cubic_metre / max_net_load
    if cubic_metre >= max_volume_cubic_metres:
     return cubic_metre - max_volume_cubic_metres
    else:
     print("this much left to fill")
     return max_volume_cubic_metres - cubic_metre
```

Comment: Thanks for your help I have now figured it out